# Mysql Delete Record older than 10 second

Tags: mysql

hi guys im frustating about this query,

lets make this clear first

i have the table :

table1
table2
table3
table4

and each tables have some foreign key relation with other let says

table1 --> table2 --> table3 --> table 4

but only table3 have date-time column

how can i delete record from those table if older than 10 seconds

i try

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)

DELETE FROM table2 WHERE timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
DELETE FROM table3 WHERE timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
DELETE FROM table4 WHERE timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
```

but its error

```
Unknown column 'timestamp' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: Maybe `ON DELETE CASCADE` will help?

Comment: don't use timestamp it may be a reserved keyword

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE FROM table1 JOIN table3 ON table1.constraint_field=table3.constraint_field WHERE timestamp > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)`

And remember to set CASCADE on DELETE for the constraints.